# How to handle the AWS lambda function error in nodejs

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, nodejs-server, aws-lambda-layers

I am using node js to get the HTTPS response from the server . The response contains more than 6291556 bytes When I execute this function I got the below exception. Is there any best way to handle the error

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Response payload size exceeded the maximum allowed payload size (6291556 bytes).",
  "errorType": "Function.ResponseSizeTooLarge"
}
```

Sample code

```
var res = await beResult(event.id);
    
      const response = {
          statusCode: 200,
          body: res,
      };
      return response;
    };
    
    async function beResult(id) {
      const url = "https://api.com/request/";    
      const params = {
          method: "GET",
          mode: "cors",
          headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, OPTIONS",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          }
      };
      const urlId= url + id;
      return await fetch(urlId, params).then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => { return json;});
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Lambda functions have restrictions on the request and response size.

You can read about them on the [Lambda quotas page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html) of the developer guide.

Invocation payload (request and response)

- 6 MB (synchronous)
- 256 KB (asynchronous)

Comment: is it possible to increase the limit?

Comment: No, is the response a document? Or an image? Can it be uploaded to S3 and then a reference be returned as a response instead of the whole payload.

Comment: The response is a JSON

Comment: If your JSON document is made up of a list of things, can you implement paging to reduce the size?